# How to know which drives are chkdsk on startup

Tags: windows-10, boot, chkdsk, disk-utility

I have a PC with 2 internal disks A (2 partitions, bitlocked) and B (1 partition), running Windows 10 v2004 (20H1).

When booting with B, a checkdisk is runned at startup. I cancel it before the 8 seconds.
When in windows if I test the disk with `chkntfs C:`, it says that the disk is clean.
The A disk is disabled in disk manager, and of course is not shown in the explorer.

When I boot on A (with disk B powered off), there are no chkdsk launched at startup.
When in windows if I test the disk with `chkntfs C:` and `chkntfs D:`, it says that the disk is clean.

I tried disabling the check at startup when booting with B with `chkntfs /X C:` when in windows, with no effect.
So how can I know, when booting with B, which disks are going to be checked ?

Comment: Try to [disable fast startup](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-turn-off-fast-startup-windows-10-a.html) in both Windows versions.

Comment: @harrymc: it is already disabled

Comment: Boot B and use `regedit` to check in registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager`, if the item `BootExecute` has the value `autocheck autochk *`.

Comment: @harrymc:The value of this item is `autocheck autochk /k:C *`

Comment: @harrymc:So as far as I can see, no checkdisk should be launched at startup

Comment: Try to set it the same as my value.

Comment: @harrymc: Ok tried, does not change anything

Comment: What is your mechanism for booting from A or B, and how are you powering off the disks?

Comment: @harrymc:the A disk is inside the computer. The B disk is removable, in an internal 5.25 dock (SATA connected) having an on/off switch. When I want to boot B, I power on the dock and ensure to boot on B using the BIOS F11 key at boot. When I want to boot on A, I power off the dock before booting. Of course on/off actions with the computer turned off.

Comment: When booting from B, how do you shutdown? You could also just delete `BootExecute` or make it empty.

Comment: @harrymc:Windows->Shutdown computer. Then when everything is off, I turn the power switch of the internal dock to Off if I want to boot with A the next tile.

Comment: @harrymc: is deleting `BootExecute` or making it empty a genuine and safe solution ? Because on A, it is set to `autocheck autochk *`

Comment: I'm only advising it for B and only as a test. I think that because B is an external disk, the shutdown is not complete, which causes the chkdsk.

Comment: @harrymc:Well, as B is SATA connected to an internal dock, it is not really an external disk.

Comment: Windows might treat it as such.

Comment: @harrymc: Ok, just note that this didn't happen during monthes. BTW, with chkntfs /X C: and `autocheck autochk /k:C *` in the registry, why do this still happen. How can I know if B disk will be the only one to be checked ?

Comment: Some Windows update might be responsible for it. I agree that by the documentation this shouldn't be happening. You may submit a bug-report to Microsoft, in my opinion.